Are These Flutter Errors
I see a lot of this messages after trying to test run my app on VSCode. Are these errors or normal stuff? Will this have a negative impact on my app?
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3846:18                          updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5505:16                          performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5643:11                          performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3846:18                          updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5505:16                          performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5643:11                          performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5196:7                           rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5462:5                           [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3846:18                          updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4335:15                          inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3846:18                          updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5505:16                          performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3846:18                          updateChild

Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.


yes , it is better to fix before release

These errors may not come to your attention in development mode. Although it may seem like a minor problem, while your application is live, the screens where you receive this error will most likely not be visible to users and users will see a gray screen instead.
"Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."
This error is usually caused by using the wrong widget.
Like Expanded etc.
Your widget tree definitely has such a problem.
